# fullscreen overlay with css/jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'm trying to make a "huge" div that fills all the viewport with opacity 0.4 or whatever. The problem is how to do it. I tried making a div with all my page content inside and give it this properties:

```
.div{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:#000;
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

since that didn't work, i tried to add z-index and put a high value but it didn't work either.
any idea?
i want to make something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

The CSS:

```
#fade-wrapper {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hTQb8/1/

Comment: It should work fine as long as your JS/jQuery is correct and as long as you set your `.div` CSS as I have above for `#fade-wrapper`. Maybe you could post your JS/jQuery as well?

Comment: Also, make sure you do a hard refresh when you try to view changes, because the browser probably shows you cached versions of the site.

Comment: i could :D with a little modification, thanks, really!

Comment: probably want to use height 100% and width 100% for IE8 or below

Comment: forgot, if you are placing this over something like a map, you also need to make sure it has a pretty high z-index.

Answer (score -1):

try this

HTML

```
<div class="div_out">
  <div class="div_in">the content in this div will be placed above the overlay</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.div_out{
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:#000;
opacity:0.5;
position:fixed;//you forgot from this point
top:-22px;
left:-22px;
margin-top:22px;
margin-left:22px;
}
.div_in{
 width:90%;
 height:90%;
 margin:0 auto;     
 margin-top:1.5%;
 background color:white;
 }
```